# BIND9 on CentOS issue querying from Windows

Tags: windows-7, dns, centos, bind

I've just built a CentOS 6 server and configured BIND9 (named) to run. Zone files are configured and `NSLOOKUP`, `DIG` and `HOST` are all working from the CentOS box.

When I move to my Windows PC, nslookup gives me `can't find centos: No response from server` (centos is the hostname).

I don't have another linux machine to test with... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have forgotten to open port 53 in the firewall, so BIND is not reachable from the "real" network, while working perfectly via loopback.

Look in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.

Comment: This was the issue, although I thought I had stopped the iptables process so ignored this step initially.